# Log the actual SQL query using ActiveRecord with Yii2?

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, logging, yii2

I'm doing this:

```
$students = Student::find()->all();
    return $this->render('process', array('students' => $students));
```

and then this in the view:

```
foreach($students as $student)
    {
        echo $student->name . ', &nbsp;';
        echo $student->getQuizActivitiesCount(); ?> <br /> <?php
    }
```

i would like to see the sql query being performed. a student "has many" quiz activities, and the query performs perfectly, but i need to see the raw SQL. is this possible?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Method 1**

With relations that return `yii\db\ActiveQuery` instance it's possible to extract the raw SQL query directly in code for example with `var_dump()`.

For example if we have `user` relation:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

You can then `var_dump()` the raw SQL like that:

```
var_dump($model->getUser()->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql);
exit();
```

Note that you should call it like that and not `$model->user->...` (the latter returns `User` instance).

But in your case it's not possible because `count()` immediately returns `int`. You can `var_dump()` partial query without `count()`, but I think it's not convenient.

Note that you can use this method for dumping generated SQL of any `ActiveQuery` instances (not only those that were returned by relation), for example:

```
$query = User::find()->where(['status' => User::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
var_dump($query->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql);
exit();
```

**Method 2**

This is much simpler in my opinion and I personally prefer this one when debugging SQL queries.

Yii 2 has built-in debug module. Just add this to your config:

```
'modules' => [
    'debug' => [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ],
],
```

Make sure you only have it locally and not on production. If needed, also change `allowedIPs` property.

This gives you functional panel at the bottom of the page. Find the `DB` word and click on either count or time. On this page you can view all executed queries and filter them.
I usually don't filter them in Grid and use standard browser search to quickly navigate through and find the necessary query (using the table name as keyword for example).

**Method 3**

Just make an error in query, for example in column name - `cityy` instead of `city`. This will result as database exception and then you can instantly see the generated query in error message.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to see relational queries with all these methods in console application. Added an answer showing how I solved it.

Comment: I add it inside components array in common/config/main-local but it doesn't work:
        'modules' => [
            'debug' => [
                'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
            ],
        ],

Comment: $query = User::find()->where(['status' => User::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
var_dump($query->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql);
exit(); worked for me

Answer (score 25):

If you want to log all relational queries of `ActiveRecord` in console application all proposed methods don't help. They show only main SQL on active record's table, `\yii\debug\Module` works only in browser.

Alternative method to get all executed SQL queries is to log them by adding specific [FileTarget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-log-filetarget.html) to configuration:

```
'log' => [
    'targets' => [[
        ...
    ], [
        'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
        'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/profile.log',
        'logVars' => [],
        'levels' => ['profile'],
        'categories' => ['yii\db\Command::query'],
        'prefix' => function($message) {
            return '';
        }
    ]]
]
```

**UPDATE**

In order to log insert/update/delete queries one should also add `yii\db\Command::execute` category:

```
'categories' => ['yii\db\Command::query', 'yii\db\Command::execute']
```

Comment: Good addition! But I think method with making error will still work in CLI, exception will be thrown and full query will be shown,

Comment: @arogachev, It will show you only single SQL query where an error occurs. If you build active query with many eager loaded relations it's very difficult (almost impossible) to use 'cause it requires you to make errors in each relation in series, and it doesn't describe the whole situation. You also could miss some queries that you don't expect to be executed or forget about.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Logging is better in this case.

Comment: @RobySottini, you should add it to [application's configuration file](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-configurations#application-configurations).

Comment: @RobySottini, it's `config/web.php` file for [basic application template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic).

Answer (score 18):

you can try this, assume you have a query given like:

```
$query = new Books::find()->where('author=2');
echo $query->createCommand()->sql;
```

or to get the SQL with all parameters included try:

```
$query->createCommand()->getRawSql()
```

Answer (score 16):

In addition to arogachev answer, when you already work with an `ActiveQuery` object, here is the line I search to view the rawsql.

```
/* @var $studentQuery ActiveQuery */
$studentQuery = Student::Find();
// Construct the query as you want it
$studentQuery->where("status=3")->orderBy("grade ASC");

// Get the rawsql
var_dump($studentQuery->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql);

// Run the query
$studentQuery->all();
```

Comment: How it's different from my answer? `$model->getUser()` is `ActiveQuery` instance too.

Comment: Added additional note about that to my answer, but common principle is the same.

Answer (score 5):

when you have a query object you can also use

```
$query->createCommand()->getRawSql()
```

to return the Raw SQL with the parameters included or

```
$query->createCommand()->sql
```

which will output the Sql with parameters separately.

Answer (score 5):

In order to log/track every/**all** queries:

extend `\yii\db\Connection` and override `createCommand` method, like below:

```
namespace app\base;

class Connection extends \yii\db\Connection {

    public function createCommand($sql = null, $params = array()) {
        $createCommand = parent::createCommand($sql, $params);
        $rawSql = $createCommand->getRawSql();
         // ########### $rawSql -> LOG IT / OR DO ANYTHING YOU WANT WITH IT
        return $createCommand;
    }
}
```

Then, simply change your db connection in your db config like below:

```
'db' => [
        'class' => 'app\base\Connection', //  #### HERE 
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'username' => 'uname',
        'password' => 'pwd',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

Now, you can track/read/... all queries executed by `db` connection.

Answer (score 2):

Try like,

```
$query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
        ->update('table_name', ['title' => 'MyTitle'],['id' => '1']);

var_dump($query->getRawSql()); die();
$query->execute();
```

Output:

```
string 'UPDATE `table_name` 
        SET `title`='MyTitle' WHERE `id`='1'
' (length=204)
```