# Yii2: get raw sql of model->save()

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

I want to add record to a table with `ActiveRecord`.

Here is my code:

```
$model = new Article();
$model->title = 'test title';
$model->content = 'test content';
$model->category_id = 1;
$model->author_id = 1;
if ($model->validate()) {
    $model->save();
}
```

`$model->validate()` returns `true`, but `$model->save()` returns `false`.

How to find generated raw sql of `$model->save()`?

Meanwhile:

`$model->save()->rawSql` is `null` and `$model->getErrors()` returns empty array.

In debug, all queries are logged, but I did not find any insert or update query.

Comment: You can have look into runtime/logs/app.log if you are in debug mode. Queries get also logged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$model->save()->rawSql` call can not return `null`, it must throw an exception that you are trying to access property of non-object. `$model->save()` returns `boolean` value - either query executed successfully or not.

If `$model->getErrors()` returns empty array and query was not executed at all I'm pretty sure that something is wrong with model event handlers, especially `beforeSave()`, check it, it should not `return false`. Also check attached behaviors event handlers.

As for getting query. It's useless if it simply was not executed, but if it was, here are some ways to achieve it:

**1)** Probably the best way. Use debug panel. I also mentioned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389146/log-the-actual-sql-query-using-activerecord-with-yii2/27393127#27393127).

**2)** Look at logs as @robsch adviced.

You can't directly get raw SQL in code with `$model->save()`, It will call either `insert()` or `update()`. If you are interested, here is the part of code for `insertInternal()`:

```
$values = $this->getDirtyAttributes($attributes);
if (empty($values)) {
    foreach ($this->getPrimaryKey(true) as $key => $value) {
        $values[$key] = $value;
    }
}
$db = static::getDb();
$command = $db->createCommand()->insert($this->tableName(), $values);
if (!$command->execute()) {
    return false;
}
```

If you call `$command->rawSql` you will get raw sql but you can't do that outside because the command is formed internally.

**P.S.** This piece of code:

```
if ($model->validate()) {
    $model->save();
}
```

doesn't make sense because `$model->save()` will call `$model->validate()` internally.

Comment: the problem was from `beforeSave`

Answer (score 1):

This code won't show you exactly the raw sql but you'll get the query pre binding and the params

```php
try {
    // this will simulate $model->save();
    $builder = $model->getCommandBuilder();
    $table = $model->getTableSchema();
    $command = $builder->createInsertCommand($table, $model->getAttributes());
    $command->_connection->enableParamLogging = true;
    $command->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // getText() will print the query with the binding params
    // getAttributes() will give you the attributes injected
    var_dump($command->getText());               
    var_dump($model->getAttributes());
    die();
}
```

The result will look like:

```
"INSERT INTO `fruit` (`order`, `name`, `season`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1,:yp2)"

array(2) {
  ["order"] =>  int(1),
  ["name"] =>  null,
  ["season"] =>  null
}
```