# Getting raw sql in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have the query:

```
$popular = self::find()
    ->from(self::tableName() . ' as t')
    ->with('user');
```

When I try to print sql:

```
$popular->createCommand()->rawSql
```

It gives me:

```
SELECT * FROM "themes" "t"
```

So can I get full raw query with "join":

```
SELECT * FROM "themes" "t" LEFT JOIN "users" u ON u.user_id = t.author_id
```

Answer (score 13):

It's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389146/log-the-actual-sql-query-using-activerecord-with-yii2/27393127#27393127).

You can `var_dump` generated SQL for `ActiveQuery` instances like this:

```
var_dump($query->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql);
```

However, I recommend to use built-in debug model and panel.

**P.S.** As for your particular query - `with()` does not perform `JOIN`, instead it performs additional query and fills relation attributes with the actual related records. To use `JOIN`, you need explicitly specify it for example with `joinWith()`.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will help

```
$query = new Query;

$query  ->select(['themes.c1 AS d1', 'themes.c2 As d2..'])

        ->from('themes')

        ->leftJoin('users', 'users.user_id = themes.author_id');

$command = $query->createCommand();

$data = $command->queryAll();
```

Comment: How it will help? OP wants to get SQL.