# How to Speed Up the performance of web application developed by using Yii 2.0 Framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Actually i need to increase the performance speed in my web application developed by using Yii 2 .0 Framework

I have made a CRM using Yii2 Framework, That contains a *large database*, in that database particular table called `Employee` contains 20,000 employee records, so while executing query to retrieve data from table, it takes time to execute.

This makes it troublesome for me to use this application.

UPDATED
code:

```
public function actionLists($id)
    {
         $countClaimprocess = Employee::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->count();

    $claimprocess1 = Employee::find()
            ->select('employee_id')
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->one();

    $claimprocess2 = Employee::find()
            ->select('importcompany_id')
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->one();

    $claim2 = $claimprocess2->importcompany_id;

    $claim = $claimprocess1->employee_id;

    $claimprocess = Employee::find()
            ->where("employee_id = '$claim'  and importcompany_id = $claim2")
            ->andwhere(" status != 'Deleted' ")
            ->all();

    }
```

The  above code is used for a dependent dropdown, that means if a admin select a `company_name`, it will show a dependent `employee_code` belonging to that `company`, and then again admin selects a `employee_code`, it will show the dependent `employee_name` and their `family` members name.

Comment: can you please post your query?

Comment: @noddy pls see above i have updated my question

Comment: Is your first query right ($countClaimprocess). Are you reading from the correct table Employee?

Comment: yes, i need to know whether contains records or not

Answer (score 0):

Start from logging your queries ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389146/log-the-actual-sql-query-using-activerecord-with-yii2)).

When you already have this query in SQL format go to your database management application (e.g. phpmyadmin) and execute `EXPLAIN [query_body];` It will show you if your table has proper indexes. If no indexes are used or you don't have any you should fix it by adding one or writing more accurate query. I bet it's not yii2 specific problem or even php but your db system.

Columns that should be indexed in `employee` table are: `employee_id`, `importcompany_id` and `status`

Also think about changing `status` column to some enumerated integer value (it's hard to properly index strings due to it's size).