# How to print converted SQL query from yii2 query

Tags: yii2

I want to print query:

```
$demo = Demo::find()->all();
```

I want to see converted SQL query with parameters:

```
createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

is showing me an error message:

> yii2 Call to a member function createCommand() on a non-object

Please help me to see the actual SQL query.

Comment: This question already been answered
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389146/log-the-actual-sql-query-using-activerecord-with-yii2>

Comment: No the the queston and the asnwer  in the link is not related to this question ..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Eg:

```
$query = Demo::find()->where(['category'=>2]);
echo $query->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$demo = Demo::find()->all();
```

returns an array of all models not the actual sql.

if you want the sql use this (this is the sql which is excecuted)

```
$query = Demo::find()->where('1');
var_dump($query->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql)
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple way is use the Active Query Builder createCommand method

```
  $sqlCommand = Demo::find()->createCommand();

  echo $sqlCommand->sql;
```

see this for refernce http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html
and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#createCommand()-detail

Comment: it showing me an error message "Call to a member function createCommand() on a non-object"

Comment: Be sure that Demo::Find() is a valid object .. and you have access  ..  eventually update your question and show your code .. where use are using this statements

Comment: yes, Demo::find()->all(); returns an array of object . and i am using this query in method of model class

Comment: You don't should use Demo::find()->all();  but Demo::find()->createCommand();  .. you must substitute all() with createComman()  if you want see the resulting query ..  Demo::find()->all();  return the row model objec  not the sql intruction for retrieve this rows

Answer (score 2):

Hiii Paritosh,
You can view the query that is being executed in SQl format by  `yii\db\Connection::createCommand()` objects like

```
$query = new \yii\db\Query;
        $query->select(['*'])
                ->from('table_demo');

        $command = $query->createCommand();

//      $command->sql returns the actual SQL
        $rows = $command->sql;
        echo $rows;
        exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to select some non-existing field, for example:

```
Demo::find()->select('nonExistingField')->all();
```

and see the debug message like this:

```
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `nonExistingField` ...
```

This way, you dont need to remove your ->all() or ->one() calls.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is probably:

```
echo Demo::find()->createCommand()->rawSql;
```