# Get Command query results as models instead of associative arrays, or turn them into it, in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I want to run a prepared query in Yii using createCommand, but get results as models instead of associative arrays.

```
class Fruit extends ActiveRecord {
    public function eat() {return this;};
}

// This will be an extremely complicated query so I need
// to write it raw without any kind of query builder
$rows = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE color = :color')
    ->bindValue('color', 'blue')->queryAll();

$fruits = magicallyTurnIntoFruit($rows);

$fruits[0]->eat()->save();
```

How do accomplish this?

Comment: why dont you use `ActiveQuery` like `Fruits::find()->all()`

Comment: I want to run a sql query without any kind of query builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findBySql` as official doc describes it [**here**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql()-detail).

As an example:

```
$customers = Customer::findBySql('SELECT * FROM customer')->all();
```

In case you need to create your `SQL` using `QueryBuilder`, and use it in `findBySql`, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389146/log-the-actual-sql-query-using-activerecord-with-yii2?noredirect=1&lq=1) or similar!

Comment: That is it! Thank you!